# Virtual Domains with Postfix and SSL

Tags: ssl, postfix

I've got a Postfix mail server setup for hosting multiple virtual domains (say `xxx.com` and `yyy.com`).

Users configure their outgoing mail server as `mail.xxx.com` and `mail.yyy.com`. All mail servers refer to the same physical Postfix server (same IP, single instance of Postfix running on this Linux server).

Which SSL certificate do I need for Postfix `smtpd_tls_cert_file` configuration option?

Or do I have to use a single certificate for `mail.xxx.com` and tell users of `yyy.com` to use `mail.xxx.com` as their outgoing server? This would break the illusion of separate virtual servers.

[Note: the domains are completely separate. These are not multiple subdomains sharing a common root].

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Or do I have to use a single certificate for mail.xxx.com and tell
>   users of yyy.com to use mail.xxx.com as their outgoing server?

Yes, ultimately you'll have to do either that or use a certificate with multiple `CommonName` or `SubjAltName` attributes.

There is no way Postfix can know which hostname the client requested. There is no such thing as i. e. the HTTP/1.1 `Host` header which indicates the requested domain and Postfix doesn't support [SNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) yet.

If you really depend on having two different domains for your mail server you'll have to run two instances of `smtpd` on two separate network interfaces/IP addresses. Usually you'd just choose a "neutral" domain and tell your users to use that.

Answer (score 22):

Actually...
If you want each domain to use a valid SSL certificate, you have 2 solutions:
use a multi-domain certificate, or set up each domain on a unique IP.
The first solution is terrible: those certificates are usually quite expensive (though you can find inexpensive ones), they will list all of the domains you wish to certify on the same cert, and, most importantly, they are only issued once, so adding just one new domain means getting an entirely new cert.

The better solution is to place each domain on its own IP, and then to match each certificate to its respective IP.

Here's how you do it in postfix.

You will first place your certificates for each domain in the **/etc/postfix/** directory (you can also create a **/etc/postfix/ssl/** directory)
Note: i use Plesk, which uses .pem certificate files, but you can also use .key and .cer files (.pem files are just a concat of .key and .cer file, in that order)

then, you need to modify the **master.cf** file in **/etc/postfix/**

originally, mine looked like this (probably because i added the last 3 IPs after i set up the server:

```
1.1.1.1- unix - n n - - smtp -o smtp_bind_address=1.1.1.1 -o smtp_bind_address6= -o smtp_address_preference=ipv4

2.2.2.2- unix - n n - - smtp -o smtp_bind_address=2.2.2.2 -o smtp_bind_address6= -o smtp_address_preference=ipv4

smtp inet n - n - - smtpd
smtps inet n - n - - smtpd -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
submission inet n - n - - smtpd -o smtpd_enforce_tls=yes -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticate d,reject -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=

3.3.3.3- unix - n n - - smtp -o smtp_bind_address=3.3.3.3 -o smtp_bind_address6= -o smtp_address_preference=ipv4

4.4.4.4- unix - n n - - smtp -o smtp_bind_address=4.4.4.4 -o smtp_bind_address6= -o smtp_address_preference=ipv4

5.5.5.5- unix - n n - - smtp -o smtp_bind_address=5.5.5.5 -o smtp_bind_address6= -o smtp_address_preference=ipv4
```

Now, to bind each certificate to its corresponding IP, you do as follows:

```
1.1.1.1- unix - n n - - smtp -o smtp_bind_address=1.1.1.1 -o smtp_bind_address6= -o smtp_address_preference=ipv4

2.2.2.2- unix - n n - - smtp -o smtp_bind_address=2.2.2.2 -o smtp_bind_address6= -o smtp_address_preference=ipv4

3.3.3.3- unix - n n - - smtp -o smtp_bind_address=3.3.3.3 -o smtp_bind_address6= -o smtp_address_preference=ipv4

4.4.4.4- unix - n n - - smtp -o smtp_bind_address=4.4.4.4 -o smtp_bind_address6= -o smtp_address_preference=ipv4

5.5.5.5- unix - n n - - smtp -o smtp_bind_address=5.5.5.5 -o smtp_bind_address6= -o smtp_address_preference=ipv4

#smtp inet n - n - - smtpd
#smtps inet n - n - - smtpd -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
#submission inet n - n - - smtpd -o smtpd_enforce_tls=yes -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=

1.1.1.1:smtp inet n - n - - smtpd -o smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/postfix/cert1.pem -o smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/postfix/cert1.pem
1.1.1.1:smtps inet n - n - - smtpd -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes -o smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/postfix/cert1.pem -o smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/postfix/cert1.pem
1.1.1.1:submission inet n - n - - smtpd -o smtpd_enforce_tls=yes -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject -o smtpd_sender_restrictions= -o smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/postfix/cert1.pem -o smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/postfix/cert1.pem

2.2.2.2:smtp inet n - n - - smtpd -o smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/postfix/cert2.pem -o smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/postfix/cert2.pem
2.2.2.2:smtps inet n - n - - smtpd -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes -o smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/postfix/cert2.pem -o smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/postfix/cert2.pem
2.2.2.2:submission inet n - n - - smtpd -o smtpd_enforce_tls=yes -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject -o smtpd_sender_restrictions= -o smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/postfix/cert2.pem -o smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/postfix/cert2.pem

3.3.3.3:smtp inet n - n - - smtpd -o smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/postfix/cert3.pem -o smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/postfix/cert3.pem
3.3.3.3:smtps inet n - n - - smtpd -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes -o smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/postfix/cert3.pem -o smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/postfix/cert3.pem
3.3.3.3:submission inet n - n - - smtpd -o smtpd_enforce_tls=yes -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject -o smtpd_sender_restrictions= -o smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/postfix/cert3.pem -o smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/postfix/cert3.pem

4.4.4.4:smtp inet n - n - - smtpd -o smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/postfix/cert4.pem -o smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/postfix/cert4.pem
4.4.4.4:smtps inet n - n - - smtpd -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes -o smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/postfix/cert4.pem -o smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/postfix/cert4.pem
4.4.4.4:submission inet n - n - - smtpd -o smtpd_enforce_tls=yes -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject -o smtpd_sender_restrictions= -o smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/postfix/cert4.pem -o smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/postfix/cert4.pem

5.5.5.5:smtp inet n - n - - smtpd -o smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/postfix/cert5.pem -o smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/postfix/cert5.pem
5.5.5.5:smtps inet n - n - - smtpd -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes -o smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/postfix/cert5.pem -o smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/postfix/cert5.pem
5.5.5.5:submission inet n - n - - smtpd -o smtpd_enforce_tls=yes -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject -o smtpd_sender_restrictions= -o smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/postfix/cert5.pem -o smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/postfix/cert5.pem
```

That's it!! (don't forget to comment out the original lines as seen above)

PS: to do the same for POP/IMAP if you use courier-imap, you simply place copies of those .pem files in **/usr/share/courier-imap/** (or in the case of Plesk, you place them in **/usr/share/** )
and you name them as follows:
imapd.pem.xx.xx.xx.xx
pop3d.pem.xx.xx.xx.xx

where xx.xx.xx.xx is the respective IP address (the 2 certificates are copies of the same file)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write such a detailed answer! I'm sure it will help someone in the future.

Comment: that's the hope! It took me a while to piece this together, and it was rare to find solutions that *actually* worked, rather than someone surmising this or that might work..

Comment: Now you can use letsencrypt to go with the first method. You can have multidomain certificates for free